# Wrong Oracle SQL script generation from EJB QL

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans-7, ejbql

I have this query

```sql
SELECT acc.Id 
  FROM Auth as auth, AccId as acc 
 WHERE acc.ownId.Id = auth.Id 
   AND acc.disabled = 0
```

Which appears to have been generated correctly:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "T1"."A_ID"."T1"."A_ID": invalid identifier
```

Obviously `acc.ownId.Id` was not generated properly.

How could this have happened?

Comment: Your error message doesn't match the SQL. There is no `T1.A_ID` in your example SQL.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name  - this is not SQL - this is ejb ql.

Comment: oracle version? running app server and the version? pls

Comment: oracle 11g. App Server GlassFish 3.2.2

Comment: I would say it is a mapping fail somewhere, as your error gives that output. Check your mappings again maybe?

Comment: Unfortunately - it looks nice and pretty and no errors in mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please show your table definition, it makes it easier.
Provide your table information and we can take a look at the create table clause.

`acc.ownId.Id` is wrong identifier for a column, if you dont put " " around it!

Check the correct column.

maybe

`acc.ownId` only? or `acc."ownId.Id"` ?

IF your column name was created as:

```
Create table AccId (
...
"ownId.Id" int,
...
);
```

It works, but I would not recommend this kind of naming.

Then of course you will need to wrapp it with " " if you use it in your query.

i.e.

> WHERE acc."ownId.Id" = auth.Id